# Get a subset of rows grouping by one of them

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am working on a ecommerce site with products, products variants, etc.
I have made a complex query that throws the following results.

```
 id | product_id | options 
----+------------+---------
  1 |          1 | 1
  2 |          1 | 1
  3 |          1 | 1
  4 |          1 | 2
  5 |          1 | 2
  6 |          1 | 3
  7 |          1 | 3
  8 |          1 | 1
  9 |          1 | 4
```

What I need to do, is selecting the first record for each different option value. In the last example I need to write a select statement to return the following rows:

```
 id | product_id | options 
----+------------+---------
  1 |          1 | 1
  4 |          1 | 2
  6 |          1 | 3
  9 |          1 | 4





select distinct (options,product_id) , id from(
      <The query that returns the rows on this question>
  ) as prodvalues
group by product_id, options;
```

But no luck with that. I am really stucked.
Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks like it should work.  Does this product what you want?

```
select options, product_id, max(id) as id
from (
      <The query that returns the rows on this question>
     ) prodvalues
group by product_id, options;
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should give the result set you asked for, ordered in the way shown, by grouping on the fields you want to see one row per combination for, and picking the minimum id field across all the matching rows:

```
SELECT MIN(id), product_id, options
FROM ( ... )
GROUP BY product_id, options
ORDER BY product_id, options
```